# Kubernetes external service faileover howto

Tags: kubernetes, failover

I have two external AcriveMQ url, say mqA and mqB which are used by pod my-pod.
Both mqA and mqB are not in kubernetes cluster, and are not managed by me.
mqA is to be normally used, thus when its unavailable (0.1% probability) then mqB can be used.

Currently if mqA is broken then my-pod crashes and tries to restart.

For me, it's ok to restart the pod or some reasonable fowntime for switching.

So basically I'd like to have a kind of faileover for external service.

Is there a common approach for this in Kubernetes? Like an [externalname](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) would be fine. So when mqA is not pingable then it will switch externalName to mqB.

Comment: Any reason why don't you want to do failover on the client side?

Comment: let's say client is supposed to be a black box

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Kubernetes does not have native concept for running active-passive workloads. At this stage you will be better off having fail over at the client side or have some custom operator logic and proxy that will do the fail over for you.

Here's very good information that you may find interesting about [active/standby proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45300) to kubernetes devs with some possible temporary solutions:

- https://github.com/amelbakry/kubernetes-active-passive
- https://github.com/andreykaipov/active-standby-controller
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45300#issuecomment-737658596